# Why Extra Space with letter "w" with font-family:arial and font-size:11px?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, internet-explorer-11, font-family

In IE 11 , the letter "w" comes with extra space. 
i.e. : "Password" becomes "Passw ord"

This only happens when font-family = arial and font-size = 11px.

```
body, table, input, select, textarea { 
        font: 11px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

anybody know the reason behind it ?

Comment: I know Helvetica caused problems on IE9+, not Arial. Is your Arial font present on your PC?

Comment: Yes, Arial font is present in my system , and also i tried to remove the Hevetica fonts, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Not reproduceable. Please post a complete page that demonstrates the issue, so that we can make sure that the issue is not caused by some other setting or special context.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like IE11 has a problem with letter spacing. To fix this follow [this article](http://jwcooney.com/2014/07/03/irregular-font-letter-spacing-in-ie11/) which says:

> ...add the Web site as a trusted site:
>
> ```
> Open up IE11
> Click on Tools on the top menu bar
> Click on Internet Options
> In the Internet Options popup, click on the Security tab
> Then click on the Trusted sites button titled Sites
> In the Trusted sites popup (if necessary) uncheck the checkbox labeled Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this
> ```
>
> zone
>       Then add your site’s base URL in the textbox labeled Add this website to this zone (for example: http://example.com)
>
> When you’ve added your site to the trusted sites list, you should see
>   that the letter spacing problem is now fixed.

Comment: Even if the suggested fix worked, it would be of no help to authors/developers, as they cannot make their visitors/users change Internet settings in their systems.

Comment: Agree, website developers cannot change client OS or favorite browser (but that was not the question).

Comment: Yes , That solve the problem but definitely this is not the solution i am looking for .